# Visual Studio Team Services REST API doesn't match documentation?

Tags: javascript, api, azure-devops

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to create a custom widget for Microsoft's Team Services dashboards but it doesn't seem to match up with the documentation.

All I'm doing is calling a simple API that's suppose to contain a list of existing queries. And I'm logging the results in the console. But the result I logged out have different properties to that of the documentation.

According to the .getQueries() API here; [REST Client APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_1#method_getqueries). It is suppose to return a `'IPromise<Contracts.QueryHierarchyItem[]>'` and QueryHierarchyItem contains a list of members listed here; [QueryHierarchyItem](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/contracts/queryhierarchyitem)

The object I log out looks something like this:

```
    Array
    ->Object
    ---> _links
    ------> html
    ---------> href
    ------> self
    ---------> href
    ------> _proto
    ---> createdDate
    ---> hasChildren
    ---> id
    ---> isFolder
    ---> isPublic
    ---> lastModifiedBy
    ------>displayName
    ------>id
    ------>_proto
    ---> lastModifiedDate
    ---> name
    ---> path
    ---> url
    ---> _proto_
```

And it doesn't have properties such as an array of `'children'` or the boolean `'isDeleted'` as described in the documentation for QueryHierarchyItem. Why is this the case? am I misunderstanding something?

By the way. Here is the code I'm using:

```
VSS.require(["TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient"],
        function(WidgetHelpers, TFS_Wit_WebApi) {
            WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();
            VSS.register("HelloWorldWidget2", function() {
                var projectId = VSS.getWebContext().project.id;

                var getQueryInfo = function(widgetSettings) {


                    //******CALL TO REST API*********//
                    return TFS_Wit_WebApi.getClient().getQueries(projectId)
                        .then(function(queries) {

                            console.log(queries);
                            return true;

                        });
                };

                return {
                    load: function(widgetSettings) {
                        // Set your title
                        var $title = $('h2.title');
                        $title.text('Query Details 3');

                        return getQueryInfo(widgetSettings);
                    }
                }
            });
            VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
        });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getQueries() has three optional parameters:

> - expand: Contracts.QueryExpand. Optional.
> - depth: number. Optional.
> - includeDeleted: boolean. Optional.

By default, the depth is "0" which means it does not include any children objects in the query/folder. So it will be blank by default. And the maximum depth you can query is 2. Try to add these optional parameters to see if you can get the result you want.

For the default value of the optional parameters, please refer to this link for details: [Get a list of queries](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries#get-a-list-of-queries).

Answer (score 0):

Because I haven't found an answer either, I played with this tonight and did get the query to return all the existing queries with the below code. The 3rd parameter(depth) is something to play with, I don't know if it breaks if you put "5" for instance, but only have 3 levels of children, etc.

The Contracts module is needed in the "VSS.require" line - documentation is lacking years into this...

```
VSS.require(["TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/Contracts"],
    function(WidgetHelpers, TFS_Wit_WebApi, contracts) {
        WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();
        VSS.register("HelloWorldWidget2", function() {
            var projectId = VSS.getWebContext().project.id;
            var getQueryInfo = function(widgetSettings) {

                //******CALL TO REST API*********//
                return TFS_Wit_WebApi.getClient().getQueries(projectId,contracts.All,2,false)
                    .then(
                            function (queries) {
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(queries));
                                return true;
                            });
            };

            return {
                load: function(widgetSettings) {
                    // Set your title
                    var $title = $('h2.title');
                    $title.text('Query Details 3');

                    return getQueryInfo(widgetSettings);
                }
            }
        });
        VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
    });
```